# What is the earliest mention of ROE as an asset pricing factor?

Tags: factor-models, asset-pricing, factor-investing

Can anyone tell me, what is the first application of ROE in an (empirical) asset pricing model? I am aware of the [2011 paper by Chen, Novy-Marx and Zhang](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1418117). Are there any earlier papers on the matter?

Comment: Warren Buffett  said he likes high ROE in 1987 (perhaps earlier), but of course not as a factor in a Quant sense. Greenblatt in 2005 said to select stocks based on high Earnings Yield and high ROC (similar to ROE but includes debt). He provided a simple backtest. I don't know any academic published papers prior to the one you mention.

Comment: the way they're using it is similar to a quality factor, though it typical incorporates a few different attributes (eg, ROE/ROA, leverage, market vol, etc).  you might try searching on the quality factor and see where you land.  I don't know of any based purely on ROE though